# Is battery storage of mains power hard

Tags: batteries, mains

I've been looking around at the different battery options for storing mains power but have found there don't seem to be a lot of offerings. Uninterruptible power supplies geared towards computer equipment seems to be the closest main stream product. Is it a big challenge to store a large amount of mains power, say 24 hours of a typical household's consumption, in a battery?

One of the reasons I ask is that where I live there are off peak electricity tariffs that are up up to 50% less than the cost of peak tariffs. If a battery could be used to store power in off peak periods for consumption in peak periods the savings could be significant even if the battery efficiency was as low as 80%.

Comment: Oh, that would be extremely expensive. Batteries are expensive and they don't last forever. If you own a large area with a tall mountain, you can effectively store the cheap energy in a PSH (pumped-storage hydroelectricity). :-)

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly possible to store relatively enormous quantities of power from mains in batteries, and it's not terribly difficult (though it is expensive)! The real issue you run into is in trying to actually run anything from that power.

What you essentially do is go find a highly efficient pure sine-wave generator [like these](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_11?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=pure+sine+wave+inverter&sprefix=pure+sine+w%2Caps%2C178) and start running your stuff off of it directly.  But if you would like to actually run say... your whole house from that battery?  You're going to run into a lot of scary things with trying to switch from mains power to your inverter (synchronization in order to do whole-house failover to backup is a whole different beast and I wouldn't recommend even trying it because you can easily hurt yourself, others, and damage equipemnt).

If you'd like to see an implementation check out [Photonic Induction's setup](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ka0MfipmdBw).  Though be aware, photonic induction, though he does a lot of extremely dangerous and stupid stuff, knows exactly what he's doing and is very safety conscious.  You'll see in the video that he has an entire specialized setup in his fusebox which prevents him from connecting both mains and battery backup at the same time.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I wasn't going to try and do it myself :). How do all the home solar kits, of which there are heaps, get around the synchronization issue? A lot of the solar kits have a battery as well as  being able to feed back into the grid.

Answer (score 2):

I've actually seen home units that do this before, well at least in some power companies test labs.   Things like [this](http://www.electronichouse.com/article/richard_grays_now_shipping_powervault_withstands_any_power_concern/), but they are crazy expensive I saw one for $30k somewhere ;)  Unless you have a background in electronic design it's probably not something you'd want to take on as just a hobby project (not to offend I didn't know what you're really trying to do).  There are a lot of safety concerns when doing something like this too.

Basically you'd need to design a charging controller, and a heavy duty regulator to charge up all the batteries, and then use an inverter to get back to AC when the power fails.

Another really cool option I've seen are these [Bloom Energy](http://www.bloomenergy.com/fuel-cell/energy-server/) boxes that convert natural gas into power (it's not a generator).  I've seen that people are using them now to help even out the cost of peak power.